# assigning letters number values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to build a program that if the user types in a letter it will print the number value that I assign to the letter instead of the letter itself.

So if I type the letter 'a', I want it to print the number '20'

**The code I have so far:**

```
letter = raw_input("Type a letter: ") 
a == 20
b == 50
c == 90
if letter == a:
    print a
```

Comment: `if letter == "a"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a `dictionary`

```
letter = raw_input("Type a letter: ")
d={}
d['a']=  20
d['b'] = 50
d['c'] = 90

if letter in d:
    print d[letter]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
letter = raw_input("Type a letter: ") 

a = dict(a=20, b=50, c=90)
if a.has_key(letter):
    print a, "\n", a[letter]
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoudn't be doing

```
a == 20, b == 50 or c == 90
```

because these are boolean expresions that will evaluate to True or False.